# How to use shiny actionButton to show & hide text output?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to write a simple shiny app with an `actionButton`.  When the `actionButton` is pressed, some text output should be printed directly below.  The code below takes me part way to a solution:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI( fluidPage(
    actionButton("button", "don't press the button"),
    verbatimTextOutput("text")
  )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      output$text <- renderText({"ahh you pressed it"})
    })
  }
)
```

There are two things I'd like to change, but not sure how:

1) The code above shows an empty gray box before the button is pressed - I'd like there to be nothing there prior to the button being pressed.  It looks like `conditionalPanel` might be the right approach, but not sure how to implement this.

2) Can the above code be adapted so that once the button is pressed a second time, the text output is hidden again?

Comment: 1) I cannot confirm that - no gray box here. 2) you can use the `shinyjs` package, include `useShinyjs()` in `fluidPage`, set up text as `hidden(verbatimTextOutput("text"))` and add ` toggle("text")` in the ovbserver, so that the hidden/visible status of _text_  is toggled on each click.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this with `shinyjs`, `hidden` and `toggle`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(useShinyjs(), 
    actionButton("button", "don't press the button"),
    hidden(
      div(id='text_div',
        verbatimTextOutput("text")
        )
    )
  )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      toggle('text_div')
      output$text <- renderText({"ahh you pressed it"})
    })

  }
)
```