# Shiny app - hide/show text comment under the plot after clicking checkbox

Tags: r, shiny

I want to build an app with the checkbox asking whether to show additional text comments under the figures.

I would like to display set of plots with or without an explanation - this shall be left to the user, whether they need more info or not.

Here are some dummy comments:
#info for box1:
"This is the red histogram"

#info for box2:
"This is the blue histogram"

Here is a dummy app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


data <-  rnorm(10000, mean=8, sd=1.3)
variable <- "This is the blue histogram"

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    skin = "black",
    dashboardHeader(
      title = "Example app",
      titleWidth = 300
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
      checkboxInput("show_comment",
                    label = "Show comment?",
                    value = FALSE)
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      box(title = "First histogram",
          status= "warning",
          plotOutput("plot1", height=300)

      ),

      box(title = "Second histogram",
          status= "warning",
          plotOutput("plot2", height=300),
          hidden(
            div(id='text_div',
                verbatimTextOutput("text")))

      )

    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      hist(data, breaks=40, col="red", xlim=c(2,14), ylim=c(0,800))
    })

    output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
      hist(data, breaks=20, col="blue", xlim=c(2,34), ylim=c(0,1000))
    })


    observeEvent(input$show_comment, {
      toggle('text_div')
      output$text <- renderText({ paste0(variable)})
    })


  }
)
```

The above code does not work properly - it displays comment no matter if the checkbox is clicked or not. I'd like to make it work, therefore seek for advice here.

I was trying to do it on my own using following hints, to no avail:
[How to use shiny actionButton to show & hide text output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44586505/how-to-use-shiny-actionbutton-to-show-hide-text-output)

This syntax is too complex for me as I am a beginner with shiny, so I was not able to troubleshoot my problem with hints from this thread:
[Show and hide text in modularized shiny app based on actionButton() and shinyJS()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70568369/show-and-hide-text-in-modularized-shiny-app-based-on-actionbutton-and-shinyjs)

I also tried ths:
[Hide/show outputs Shiny R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136029/hide-show-outputs-shiny-r)

And here is the attempt of using above hint:
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

```
data <-  rnorm(10000, mean=8, sd=1.3)
variable <- "This is the blue histogram"

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(

    skin = "black",
    dashboardHeader(
      title = "Example app",
      titleWidth = 300
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
      checkboxInput("show_comment",
                    label = "Show comment?",
                    value = FALSE)
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      box(title = "First histogram",
          status= "warning",
          plotOutput("plot1", height=300)

      ),

      box(title = "Second histogram",
          status= "warning",
          plotOutput("plot2", height=300),
          renderText("text", span(variable))

      )

    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      hist(data, breaks=40, col="red", xlim=c(2,14), ylim=c(0,800))
    })

    output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
      hist(data, breaks=20, col="blue", xlim=c(2,34), ylim=c(0,1000))
    })


    observeEvent(input$show_comment, {
      # every time the button is pressed, alternate between hiding and showing the plot
      toggle("text")
    })


  }
)
```

I want to put the comments inside the same box, along with the plot - this is why I am trying to enclose it with the box command. However, if it is impossible - I would be glad of any other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time I use `shinyjs` so there might be a better approach. But as I understand it from the docs you first have to add `useShinyjs()` in your UI code

> in order for all other shinyjs functions to work.

Second, there is no need to wrap the `div` for your comment in `hidden()`. Third, instead of using `observeEvent` I followed the example in `?toggle` and use an `observe` where I add the state of your checkbox as the `condition` to trigger the toggle.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

data <- rnorm(10000, mean = 8, sd = 1.3)
variable <- "This is the blue histogram"

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    skin = "black",
    dashboardHeader(
      title = "Example app",
      titleWidth = 300
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
      checkboxInput("show_comment",
        label = "Show comment?",
        value = FALSE
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      box(
        title = "First histogram",
        status = "warning",
        plotOutput("plot1", height = 300)
      ),
      box(
        title = "Second histogram",
        status = "warning",
        plotOutput("plot2", height = 300),
        div(id = "text_div",
            verbatimTextOutput("text")
          )
      )
    ),
    useShinyjs()
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      hist(data, breaks = 40, col = "red", xlim = c(2, 14), ylim = c(0, 800))
    })

    output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
      hist(data, breaks = 20, col = "blue", xlim = c(2, 34), ylim = c(0, 1000))
    })

    observe({
      toggle(id = "text_div", condition = input$show_comment)
      output$text <- renderText({
        paste0(variable)
      })
    })
  }
)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7437
```

[image]

[image]